# The wall outlets and lights in 2 of my rooms in my house are not working

Tags: electrical

The wall outlets and lights in 2 of my rooms in my house are not working and all the breakers are switched on.... this happened after I kept turning my main breaker on and off to fix a light because the breakers wasn’t labeled for certain parts of the house...
How can I fix this???

Comment: How many total breakers do you have?  Would you say that about half the house is without power?

Comment: turn every single breaker switch off then back on. I've seen some old/cheap/faulty ones that look almost identical when tripped as they do when on.

Comment: In one room only lights are not working and in the other nothing is working . So only 2

Comment: Slightly OT: Since you've already had to reset all the clocks, VCRs, etc. and you're messing with the electricity anyway, now would be a _great_ time to get the breakers labeled. Turn on every light & plug something (light or radio) into every outlet. Turn off a breaker & see what goes out. Label the breaker. Lather, rinse, repeat until all breakers are labeled. If you're still "under quarantine" this is a great way to pass an afternoon, and future you will thank present you for not having to turn power off to the whole house anymore.

Comment: I agree with freeman, my houses usually have the breaker number on the face plate if main and sub a1 is main #1 and b1 is sub #1at least on the receptacle under the screw when my wife complains . Same with light switches. This is one of the first things I do on my homes and flips, I want to know what and the expected load so if there is a problem I can make a simple change and eliminate most problems with 1 or 2 minor comments circuits added in many homes.

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like a bad connection, if both rooms share a common wall and the receptacles are on that same wall it is very likely you have a loose connection on the neutral white or hot black , most common is a backstab failure the push in connectors. Usually the last working receptacle or first non working one is normally the location of the failure, you need to figure out where the feed comes from and find where the problem starts, work from the location that is closest to the breaker panel. The last working device or first non working is normally the point of failure.